# issue with html5 video via firefox

Tags: html, video

My html5 videos work on local server firefox and all browsers.

However, HTML5-video on web server on FF only (chrome / safari work), it doesn't work.  When I right click and view video, the video shows / loads / downloads.
;;com/clients/hmg/what-we%27ve-done.php?i=tv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may need to set the mime-type on your server for the videos you're trying to serve.

[Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html#video-mime-types) offers a very good explanation on how to properly do this.

Essentially, you'll want to have an .htaccess file with the following included

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) also offers some more information on this, too!